# TM tag in TOC doesn't match TM in content

Tags: dita, dita-ot

We noticed a situation (PDF) where the  reg mark in the TOC entry generated the symbol a bit higher than it appears in the content.

Here's a screencap. The top is the TOC and you can see the registered mark is much higher than the bottom example which is the Chapter title and content.
[image]

This is using DITA-OT 1.7.3 default PDF2 plugin.

I looked through topic.fo and both use:
`<fo:inline line-height="100%" font-family="Helvetica, Arial Unicode MS" baseline-shift="20%" font-size="smaller">®</fo:inline>`

But they each use a different wrapper.

The TOC uses:
`<fo:inline end-indent="14pt" keep-together.within-line="auto" line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts" font-family="Helvetica, Arial Unicode MS">`

The Content uses:
`<fo:inline baseline-shift="20%" font-size="75%" line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts">`

I looked through the TOC styling a bit but I'm not seeing where to make the adjustment. 
I'm guessing the toc needs: baseline-shift="20%" font-size="75%"

This is a minor issue but is there any insight on where to make the adjustments so they're consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that making the change you describe would give you what you expect. I have a feeling if you make those changes to the TOC wrapper, you may wind up with the entire content of the TOC smaller. You may want to change the line-height-shift-adjustment for the TOC wrapper to a value of consider-shifts to see what that does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are also mistaken because in no way does that image of the TOC depict font-family as Helvetica or Arial Unicode as the font used.